# pymol ignore hidden object in python script

Tags: python, pymol

I'm writing a python script, run from the PyMol command line, to draw distances between specific nuclei. It runs! What I'm trying to do now is to draw distances only between chains that are not hidden in the PyMol viewer. This would be convenient as it would allow me to simply open a PDB file, hide the chains I don't need, and run the script to draw distances on only the chains shown. Is this possible?

Ideally, I'd have an if statement along the line of:

```
if cmd.hide(object) == False:
    cmd.distance(...)
```

To be clear, I understand that `cmd.hide()` probably can't function as a Boolean. I've been looking through PyMol documentation but haven't found anything like that yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to check whether an object is visible or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [selection keyword](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Selection_Algebra) `visible` (abbreviated `v.`) to select only objects that are visible. For example, if you want to list all visible objects, you can use the following script:

```
visible_objects = cmd.get_object_list('(visible)')
for obj in visible_objects:
    print(obj)
```